# When is the probability of countable union equal to the limit of probabilities of finite unions?

Tags: probability, limits

Lets say there are arbitrary sequence of sets $A_i$. When does the following below equation hold?, i.e., what specific properties of $A_i$ would make it invalid $$P\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_i\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty}P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_i\right)$$

Comment: If the sets $A_i$ are measurable, this equality holds.

Comment: Given just an arbitrary sequence of events $A_i$ with no further information, how does one say they are measurable or not?

Comment: An event is a measurable set, [by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_%28probability_theory%29#Events_in_probability_spaces).