# Show Probability of Countable Union Equals to the Limit of Probability of Finite Union

Tags: probability, limits

Essentially how to show that $$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty}P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_i\right)$$
holds (given $A_i$ are some sets of events)? A similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117306/when-is-the-probability-of-countable-union-equal-to-the-limit-of-probabilities-o) is here, but I would like to get some hints of proving it. Especially what does the limit here means. Thank you very much in advance!

(I haven't touch probability theory for a long time so maybe I am missing some very important concepts)

Comment: What the limit means here is that for any $i > 1$, if there exists an element $x \in A_i$, then that element is also in this union.

Comment: Thanks @RolandKillian! Does that mean when n approaching infinity, all A in the event space will be unioned and essentially the probability will reach 1?

Comment: The probability will only reach 1 if the union of all the sets contains almost all of the event space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the events $B_n = \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$. Each $B_n$ is the event that "an event covered by any of the $A_i$ up to and including $A_n$ happens". Then $p_n P(B_n)$ is the probability that an event from the first $A_n$ occurs, and this creates a sequence of probabilities $p_1, p_2, \ldots$ - noting that this sequence is (a) bounded (because they're probabilities) and (b) increasing (since $B_1 \subset B_2 \subset \ldots \subset B_n$, and hence $P(B_1) \leq P(B_2) \leq \ldots \leq P(B_n)$).

Then we can take the limit, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} p_n$, which is the limit of this sequence. But that's just $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i)$, i.e. it's the limit of the probability of "an event covered by at least one out of $A_1$ up to $A_n$ occurs", as $n$ goes to infinity.

By comparison, $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ is the union of all of the events $A_i$, i.e. it's the event of "something covered by any of the infinite $A_i$".

Intuitively, these should be the same, but of course the point is that you want to formally prove that they're consistent.

For example, consider the event $A_i$ being "I roll a 1 on the $i$-th roll of a fair six-sided die". So $B_3 = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3$ is the event "I roll a 1 on at least one of the first three rolls", and $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ is "I roll a 1 at some point in an infinite number of die rolls". It's pretty standard probability calculations to show that $P(B_n) = 1-(\frac{5}{6})^n$, so the sequence of $p_n$ goes something like 0.1667, 0.3057, 0.4213, ... and you can show that this tends towards 1.

However, not every countable union of events is going to converge to 1, since it's easy to construct a sequence of $A_i$ that don't cover the entire event space. As a basic example, if I flip a coin once and each $A_i$ is the event that I look at it and see heads, then $\bigcup A_i = A_1$ and $P(\bigcup A_i) = 0.5$ because it doesn't matter how many times I look at that coin on the table, it's not going to give a different result.